# Watchdog timeout is too short

Tags: c, embedded, stm32, watchdog

I have a conceptual question, I'm currently working on a project that have to implement a watchdog timer to ensure that the code works properly, I'm using a STM32F4, from the datasheet I can see that the max timeout allow by the IWDG (independent Watchdog) is 32768 ms, I'm using a SIM800L for communication via GPRS, so some communications take longer than that, during this process the UC is busy waiting for the answers, so it cannot reset the IWDG, so I was thinking on deactivating the Watchdog in those parts, or implement my own watchdog whit a timer and a simple reset function so can make longer timeout periods.

My question is:

Is this a sign of a flaw on my code design? Should I instead adapt my code to reset the IWDG every 30 seconds or so and never deactivate it? Is implementing my own WDG with a timer bad practice?

Comment: No, you need to reset the watchdog counter before it expires.

Comment: If your operations in general take longer than 32seconds(!) I'd say your design is wrong. I have better experience with using a non-blocking design (i.e. interrupt-driven IO/peripherals). I worked 10 years in embedded, and usually had 500-1000µs cycle times in most products (0.5M-1.5M LoC all incl, STM32-M3 stdperiph libs etc.). This requires careful design and measuring timing of everything. –

Comment: Yeah, writing non-blocking code is the way to go.  You should have a main loop that takes on the order of a millisecond to run, and it can both clear the watchdog timer and check to see if new data from the GPS is available.  Another benefit of non-blocking code is that when the project requirements change and you need to add features, you just add them to your main loop and you might not have to reengineer everything.

Answer (score 4):

> ¿is this a sign of a flaw on my code design?,
> ¿should instead adapt my
> code to renew the IWDG every 30 seconds or so?

No, you simply need to write the key register or load a new value to the downcounter before the downcounter reaches zero. It shows the watchdog that your software is alive and no reset is needed.

> during this process the UC is busy waiting for the answers, so it
> cannot reset the IWDG

This means that your implementation is bad. You need to implement it non-blocking way. It is not dificult.

> ¿implementing my own
> WDG whit a timer is a bad practice?

It is a very bad idea. What will happen if your program hardfault? Your own watchdog will be useless. Hardware WDG is also clocked from its one clock source - so if your program does something wrong with the clocks - it will still work.

Comment: Thanks! I still have questions tho, what should I do if my code is halt because is doing some operations in blocking mode, and those take longer than 32 seconds, then it won't be fast enough to reset the IWDG, but that doesn't mean that the code reached a problem (dead lock or something like that), the code sometimes would restart itself because it would have reach a false positive, my question was aiming to this escenario

Comment: @Electromosaw You don't need to block for 32 seconds at a time. Much less will do :) Use interrupts and buffers.

Answer (score 1):

Programs should never deactivate the watchdog in run-time, as that defeats the purpose of having a watchdog in the first place. Many watchdog hardware peripherals don't even allow you to disable it once enabled.

You cannot implement your own watchdog using timers, because the watchdog hardware is explicitly using a different timer than what's available to the application programmer. So if your program halts for whatever reason, your timer solution will halt as well. Forget about implementing watchdogs using on-chip timers or software. You can only implement your own watchdog using a external hardware, such as a binary counter IC or monostable multivibratior IC.

> Is this a sign of a flaw on my code design?

It is - you should not busy-wait for external resources to become available. Rather than

```
while(some_serial_bus == BUSY) {}  // bad, busy wait
```

you should be doing:

```
for(;;)
{
  kick_wdog();
  if(some_serial_bus != BUSY) // good, polling
  {
    do_stuff();
  }
}
```

When implementing the driver for the external serial bus you should provide a method to check if data is available, then allow the caller to decide whether to busy wait for that function or not. An ideal, properly written driver should never contain any busy waits nor should it contain any "sleep/delay" calls.

Comment: I think I get the point, but in the first example code (busy wait) the code has an enter point and a exit point, the second example the code hasn't, I have a little trouble understanding how to implement the concept, for example, I wan't to have function like Conect_to_server() and do all the things necessary, whit the loop scheme I'm not going to be able to do  that, I'm making a simply to use library that is WDG friendly (maybe some of this info is useful in the main question, I'm going to add it)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can stop the IWDG once it starts (nor would you want to).  I'm not familiar with the SIM800L, but your best bet would be to find a way to kick the watchdog intermittently while GPRS is operating.  You want to do this in firmware, not hardware. (Don't use a HW timer to kick the WDT because if your SW crashes, the HW timer could keep doing its thing.)  Alternatively, the STM32F4 also as a window watchdog (WWDG) timer you could use.  You might be able to configure longer window times with the WWDG.